# Akka Http websocket connection failure : IllegalStateException: can not subscribe the same subscriber multiple times

Tags: scala, websocket, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm having problems with akka http websocket connections . I handle websocket messages with handleMessagesWithSinkSource(sinkUsesActor , SFPTextMessage ). sinkUsesActor uses an actor and SFPTextMessage is a source from actorpublisher.
When i refresh the browser and it tries to reestablish the connection and error says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: can not subscribe the same subscriber multiple times .
```

How can I use the same source from actorpublisher (SFPTextMessage) in this scenario ?

```
def wsHandler: HttpRequest ⇒ HttpResponse = {
        case req: HttpRequest ⇒ req.header[UpgradeToWebsocket] match {
            case Some(upgrade) ⇒
                upgrade.handleMessagesWithSinkSource(sinkUsesActor , SFPTextMessage )
            case None ⇒ HttpResponse(400, entity = "Missing Upgrade header")
        }
    }
```